# Algebraic Topology notes similar to Ravi Vakil's AG notes

Tags: reference-request, algebraic-topology

Where can I find a massive lecture note on algebraic topology similar in style and depth to Ravi Vakil's notes are for algebraic geometry?

Comment: Maybe Hatcher's book?

Comment: I don't know if they're really similar in style, but Davis and Kirk's notes on algebraic topology are very nice and cover a lot of material. They can be found here: http://www.indiana.edu/~jfdavis/teaching/m623/book.pdfbQyMfOAhUIwmMKHfTGB0YQFggeMAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.indiana.edu%2F~jfdavis%2Fteaching%2Fm623%2Fbook.pdf&usg=AFQjCNGVF0pGGMXt630SWSCiSnrnGf27pQ&sig2=YaH9sX_i6ns2Sxmaz-5lQg

Comment: @Alex: your link doesn't work.

Comment: @Georges: thanks for letting me know, not sure what happened! A shame that the window to edit comments is so small. Oh well, here is the corrected link: http://www.indiana.edu/~jfdavis/teaching/m623/book.pdf

Comment: Thanks @Alex: your link works fine now.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to [Hatcher](https://www.math.cornell.edu/~hatcher/AT/AT.pdf) which was already mentioned, you might try out [Peter May's book](https://www.math.uchicago.edu/~may/CONCISE/ConciseRevised.pdf).